# Polylines not clearing

Tags: java, android, api, maps, polyline

Polylines are not clearing inspite of using setVisibility(false)

We created a arraylist of polylines and added to it whenever a new polyline is added. But we want to clear all the polylines without clearing the map, and there is no success.
We tried to use the setPoints option using the polyline array, but we are not able to retrieve the polyline required from the arraylist. It always gives IndexOutOfBounds error.

```
ArrayList<Polyline> polylines=new ArrayList<Polyline>();

ArrayList points = null;
            Polyline p=null;

            int counter=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                counter++;
                points = new ArrayList();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                trial1=new ArrayList<ArrayList<LatLng>>();

                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }
                trial1.add(points);
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(12);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
                lineOptions.geodesic(true);
                lineOptions.clickable(true);


                if(points.size()!=0 && points!=null && lineOptions!=null) {
                    p = mMap.addPolyline(lineOptions);
                    polylines.add(p);

                }
```

In the main function:

```
for (int required=0;required<Points.size();required++) {
        if(Points.get(required)!=FINAL.get(required)){
        polylines.get(required).setVisible(false);
        polylines.set(required,null);
        }
        drawPolylines(Points.get(required));
}
```

Where FINAL are the old locations and Points are the new locations array.

It always results in:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline.setVisible(boolean)' on a null object reference
```

Another attempt was the remove() option.

```
for(int ccc=0;ccc<polylines.size();ccc++) {
        Polyline theta=polylines.get(ccc);        //removing all the polylines in the array
        theta.remove();
     }
        polylines.clear();
        for (required=0;required<Points.size();required++) {
        if(Points.get(required)!=FINAL.get(required))
             drawPolylines(Points.get(required));   //drawing polylines again
      }
```

But this did not clear any polyline, but redrew over the existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

you can call `remove()` on polyline Object like following

suppose you added polyline like this

```
Polyline polyline = this.mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().....);
```

remove this polyline only by

```
polyline.remove();
```

// reason for redraw could be

```
for (int required=0;required<Points.size();required++) {
        if(Points.get(required)!=FINAL.get(required)){
        polylines.get(required).setVisible(false);
        polylines.set(required,null);
        }
        drawPolylines(Points.get(required)); // you are redrawing polyline here i guess 
}
```

Comment: Yes but we have multiple polylines. We tried a for loop, calling the remove option on all of them, again in vain, it's still redrawing on the map.                                                      for(int ccc=0;ccc<polylines.size();ccc++) {
                                        Polyline theta=polylines.get(ccc);
                                        theta.remove();
                                    }
                                    polylines.clear();

Comment: even if you are using for loop it should not matter

Comment: have you put any conditions before calling remove() on polyline

Comment: which code  i should consider post in question or posted in comment?

Comment: We're using one condition that checks if FINAL is empty or not, I don't think that should affect, because everything else under that block is working

Comment: The code in the comment redraws multiple polylines without removing any over the map, the code in the question causes the app to hang giving the aforementioned error.